# What does the trait after the trait name mean?

Tags: rust, traits

I came across this trait definition while reading about Rust:

```
trait Enchanter: std::fmt::Debug {
    ...
}
```

From this I understand that the name of the trait is `Enchanter`, but I do not understand what the `std::Format:Debug` part implies since it is also a trait (I think).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is declaring a [supertrait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait). It is equivalent to:

```rust
trait Enchanter
where
    Self: std::fmt::Debug,
{
}
```

In short, it requires any type that wants to implement `Enchanter` to also implement [`std::fmt::Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html). Otherwise, [an error will be raised](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=64a5254bd54fae16acd8788e83b65188):

```
error[E0277]: `S` doesn't implement `Debug`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:6
  |
4 | impl Enchanter for S {}
  |      ^^^^^^^^^ `S` cannot be formatted using `{:?}`
  |
  = help: the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `S`
  = note: add `#[derive(Debug)]` to `S` or manually `impl Debug for S`
note: required by a bound in `Enchanter`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:18
  |
1 | trait Enchanter: std::fmt::Debug {}
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Enchanter`
```